# P-value from sum of bootstrap vs ttest are different

Tags: self-study, correlation, bootstrap

I am learning about bootstrapping and I am calculating the correlation between x and y, between two independent groups with each size n=8 and n=24, respectively. Their distributions are non-Gaussian

basically in MATLAB this is what I do:

```
datax = [9.9057, 8.3095, 8.5039, 9.6073,...
     9.3390, 8.4793, 11.2583, 11.9838, 11.9044, 11.3651,...
     8.9256, 8.7969, 8.3287, 8.7668, 7.2664, 11.0119, 10.7435,...
     9.5197, 9.1035, 10.4533, 10.4424, 7.6634, 6.5135,...
     8.3041, 8.4081, 8.9557, 8.6600, 4.8351, 5.1336, 4.5175,...
     5.2102, 5.5552];

datay = [33.3401, 23.9765, 51.3204, 28.9329, 42.5752,...
     47.2980, 43.9073, 19.3809, 25.7807, 68.6852, 22.0479,...
     13.6404, 18.8664, 29.2948, 15.0274, 59.5081, 39.3324,...
     33.0013, 28.5490, 49.9514, 51.0284, 24.9240, 17.3688,...
     25.8369, 37.5792, 42.7122, 25.1384, 3.0972, 14.3448,...
     8.3398, 4.6519, 3.2049];

id1 = datax<8; %(n=8)
id2=datax>8; %(n=24) 
bn = 10000;
funcspear = @(x, y)corr(x, y, 'Type', 'Spearman');
rho1 = bootstrp(bn,funcspear,datax(id1),datay(id1));
rho2 = bootstrp(bn,funcspear,datax(id2),datay(id2));
```

to calculate the P-value of whether rho1 is bigger than rho2, I test:

```
pval = 1 - mean(rho1 > rho2); %pval = 0.0817
```

however, this result is completely different when I tried with:

```
[h, pval2] = ttest2(rho1, rho2); % h = 1; pval2=0;
```

where I get significant with ttest2 but not with pval. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you please be specific about what "completely different" means?  BTW, if a t-test always produced the same p-value as bootstrapping, what would you be doing bootstrapping for?

Comment: I am dividing data X into two X1 X1, and computing if the two data have a different *correlation* value  rho with another variable Y. I use random resampling of the data to obtain the confidence interval. Otherwise, I will only have one rho for each X1 and X2, i cant calculate a significant difference. Using bootstrap to obtain these rho for 10000 times and calculate the difference between X1, X2

Comment: Could you provide some numbers. Your edit makes no sense in relation to your previous version. If the original code is what you ran and it gave pval2=0 then there is no way this code gives pval2=0. please include output.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of applying a t-test to the *bootstrapped* data instead of the original data?  Before you answer, look at the p-values you get by changing the value of `bn`: try values like 10, 100, and 1000 and monitor what happens to the p-value as `bn` increases.

Comment: @whuber I am trying to compare the correlation between x> 8 and x<8, if one is lower than the other. I understand the purpose of sum in bootstrap data, but I thought t test is doing exactly the same thing, that is to see if one data is different than the other? that's what I understand about ttest, and if it's true, then it should give the same output, no?

Comment: That's a misconception. If you take a large enough bootstrap sample, then if there is any difference at all--no matter how small--you will detect it with a t-test.  The only conclusion it leads to is that there is a difference *in the data,* but it says nothing whatsoever about the question of interest, which is whether there is a difference *in the underlying data-generation process.*

Comment: You really need to validate your code snippets before you post them, the snippet as of current edit will not work as id is not defined before it is called for rho1

Comment: The sense of "correlation between two independent groups" is so obscure that this question needs clarification to become answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is a coding issue, but the question is framed for CV so I'm answering here rather than advising migrating over to stack overflow.

Your code for returning pval2 is asking matlab to return a boolean explaining whether the null should be rejected or not. A 0 means you cannot reject at the alpha (default 0.05 since you didn't specify in the call). This also means the ttest is agreeing with your bootstrap, and you p-value is greater than 0.05

What I think you meant to calculate was [~, pval2] = ttest2(rho1, rho2);  which returns the p-value for the test.

See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest2.html?requestedDomain=

Comment: I have edited the question; it's absolutely not a coding issue and I am asking about the bootstrapping, not MATLAB. I meant to take the pval from the output of the ttest2, which is not the same as the pvalue obtained from the sum. In my case the pvalue I get from ttest2 is 0, while from the sum is not significant at all.

Comment: Now that you've fixed your code in response to my answer it is clear there is also different issue needing addressed. Could you be more explicit about what you are intending to do? You split the groups using x, then you correlate against it. Why? Where you edit in response to an answer it is better to leave the original and indicate the new information and the difference it has made. this allows readers to understand the context of the answer.

Comment: i have added the data. @renebt